# What are the chances that Nick Szabo is Satoshi?

Tags: satoshi

Wikipedia info on [Nick Szabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Szabo).

Does his interest in Ethereum make it more or less likely it is him?

This article seems to support the suggestion: **[The man everyone thinks is the creator of bitcoin gave a speech discussing the history of the technology](http://www.businessinsider.com/nick-szabo-ethereum-bitcoin-blockchain-history-satoshi-nakamoto-2015-11?op=1?r=UK&IR=T)**

Answer (score 0):

He is one of the most likely candidates but for me his interest in Ethereum makes him less likely (than before) to be Satoshi

This article discusses some of the known plausible candidates:

http://www.coindesk.com/information/who-is-satoshi-nakamoto/